# University wifi connects but shows server not found error in mozila.

Tags: internet

I am a new ubuntu user of 16.04 version. 
I can connect to university wifi but browser shows server not found error. I can't access net in both chromium and mozila. 
Previously I was able to connect to my parents wifi network.
I live in another city for study perpose.
Can any one help me out?  Please use simple words as I am new.

Comment: Try to `ping www.google.com` or any other website from the command line

Comment: When connecting to your parents WiFi, did you use `dhcp`, or did you configure a static IP address? At your university, (i think) you need do configure dynamic IP address assignemt with dhcp.